# Make :w automatically run :nohl

Tags: command-line

I want `:nohl` to be run automatically whenever I run `:w`.

How can I set this up?

I tried

```
autocmd BufWrite * :nohl
```

in my vimrc but that's not working

---

Apparently (from comments, thanks [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble))

> Theres a note in the help somewhere about how you cant use nohl in autocmds

So how can I do it without autocmds?

Comment: Theres a note in the help somewhere about how you cant use nohl in autocmds

Comment: it is at `:h function-search-undo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is this note at [:h function-search-undo](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#function-search-undo):

```
The last used search pattern and the redo command "."
will not be changed by the function.  This also
implies that the effect of :nohlsearch is undone
when the function returns.
```

Which also applies to auto commands, so as you noted, `:au BufWritePre * :nohls` won't work.

However, you can trick Vim with using the `feedkeys()` function. I think the following should work (and does from my limited testing):

```
au BufWritePre * :call feedkeys(":nohls\n")
```

This will inject the command directly into Vims typeahead buffer and won't be marked as coming from a function that needs to be undone once the auto command returns.

Answer (score 0):

For the convenient, I usually save the file whenever I press the ESC so that I mapped ESC like this: `map <esc> :w\|:noh<cr>`
The ESC functionality still working normally.